# How to put numbers from 1-11 to the 9 circles with some rules?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

How to put numbers from 1-11 to the 9 circles below, each number can only occur once. The rules are:

- the sum of the numbers in a row must be 22
- no two consecutive numbers are connected by a line/edge.

[image]

---

**Attempt**

I have been trying but always left with 1 number that occur twice.

Comment: You can't! Note that $1 + 2+... + 11 = 66$, now there are only nine entries so some of these numbers won't be there in the circles, which means the sum of all entries is smaller than $66$. But if each row totals $22$, the total must be $66$ of all the entries, which is not possible.